# elif statment always executing even with wrong input

Tags: python, if-statement

I Have a problem with the Y and N choice in the elif statements.
If I enter n it correctly outputs the elif choice of n, but if I input y it still outputs the n choice instead of the elif choice y. I have no idea why it's doing this. Sorry about the code and if the mistakes clear as day, I'm new to python.
I have checked choice and it does keep the choice of n or y but just executes n even if y is input.

```
if os.path.exists('ExifOutput.txt'): 
                    print "The file appears to already exist, would you like to overwrite it?" 
                    Choice = raw_input("Y/N : ") 
                    if not re.match("^[Y,y,N,n]*$", Choice): 
                        print "Error! Only Choice Y or N allowed!" 
                    elif len(Choice) > 1: 
                        print "Error! Only 1 character allowed!" 
                    elif not Choice:
                        print "No choice made" 
                    elif Choice == 'N' or 'n': 
                        print "Save the old file to a different directory and try again"
                        ExifTags()
                    elif Choice == 'Y' or 'y':
                        print "The file will be overwritten by a new one"
                        ExifRetrieval(listing, FileLocation)
                        print "Completed" + "\n"
                else:
                    ExifRetrieval(listing, FileLocation)
                    print "Completed" + "\n"
```

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving `CapWords` for class names, and ``lowercase_with_underscores`` for function names and local variables.

Comment: Just FYI: If you immediately always convert your input into lowercase (or uppercase) then you won't have to worry about comparing for multiple cases, and your logic will be simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Choice == 'N' or 'n'` is always true (it's the same as `(Choice == 'N') or 'n'`). You want `Choice in ('N', 'n')`.

Comment: Ah yes so it is. Feel a fool for not seeing that, it works now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif Choice == 'N' or Choice == 'n':
```

or

```
elif Choice in ("N","n"):
```